# Delay upon sending e-mail from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a controller that sends an e-mail, and returns a "success" json response to my ajax script.

The controller looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult EmailSend(string input1)
    {

        EmailSignup person = new EmailSignup { emailhasbeensent = false, Email = input1 };

        try
        {
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Email", "PW");

            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.From = new MailAddress("Email");
            message.To.Add(person.Email);
            message.Subject = "Thank you for subscribing";
            message.Body = "You have now subscribed for our newsletter";
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            client.Send(message);
            person.emailhasbeensent = true;
            return Json(new { status = "success" });
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { status = "error" });
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately there is a delay before the success response is sent, which means that the page in which the email is being entered sort of "idles" before it receives the success response.

Is there a way to speed this process up, so that the response is sent immediately? 
If not, can a loading bar then be implemented, to show the user that something is happening "behind the scenes"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you should consider moving the time taking process off the UI thread and offload this work to some other process. For example, you can send this information (the minimum information needed for the email, the `toAddress` in your case) to a queue from which some other process will read it and send the email. The proper use of a transnational queue ensures the fault tolerance as well.

Another solution is to give this work to another Thread from the ThreadPool so that your UI thread does not need to wait until the code finishes execution. It is hard to track when the other thread fails to complete the operation successfully!

```
private void SendEmail(string emailAddress)
{
    // Your existing code to send email goes here 
    // Make sure you handle(LOG) exceptions

}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EmailSend(string input1)
{
    try
    {
        // Have another thread executes the SendEmail method
        Task.Run(() => { SendEmail(input1); });  
        return Json(new { status = "success" });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //to do : LOG exceptions
        return Json(new { status = "error" });
    }
}
```

Now if you do not want to do all those, you can show some "Loading" message on the client side so user know something is happening. The below sample changes the button text to "Please wait...". and disables the button so that user won't click it again until we get a response back from our ajax call.

```
$(function () {
    $("#emailSignup").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var _this = $(this);
        _this.text("Please wait...").attr("disabled", "disabled");

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "@Url.Action("EmailSend", "Home")",
            data: { input1: "Some value" },
        }).done(function (res) {
            if (res.status === "success") {
                $("#MailFoot").hide();
                $("#ty").show();
            }
            else {
                _this.text("Please wait...").removeAttr("disabled");
                alert("Error sending email");
            }
        });
    });
})
```

Instead of simply updating the button text, you can do whatever you want! Perhaps showing a progress bar ? A Spinner ? Simply keep a spinner image in your page (hidden initially) and show / hide as needed when the ajax call starts/ends/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Basically, if i move the Sendemail code to another method, will my code then be less prone to fail, once live? As i understand it, i prevent a bottleneck by doing this?